# What is the best way to break circular dependency between GameFlow and Controller in a game?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, circular-dependency

For example, I want to create a game, which has a GameFlow to control the game event flow, also I have some controllers (e.g.:PlayerAttackController,EnemyControllerController) for different flow.

GameFlow used to switch controllers, controllers notify GameFlow to change state:

to simple the code I don't use .cpp and use public property only:

GameFlow.h

```
class GameFlow{
public:
    int state;
    IController* controller;
    void changeState(){
        if(controller!=NULL){
            delete controller;
        }
        if(state==0){
            controller=new PlayerAttackController();
            controller->gameFlow=this;
        }else if(state==1){
            controller=new EnemyAttackController();
            controller->gameFlow=this;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
};
```

IController.h

```
class IController{
};
```

PlayerAttackController.h

```
class PlayerAttackController : public IController{
public:
    GameFlow* gameFlow;
    void buttonPressed(){
        //some player attack code
        .
        .
        .
        gameFlow->state=1;
        gameFlow->changeState();
    }
};
```

(other controllers are similar)

Now it is clear that GameFlow contains Controller, each controller contains GameFlow, is there any method to break the circular dependency between GameFlow and Controller?

Answer (score 2):

Don't define your member functions in-line with the classes. Instead, declare them in the classes (only telling the compiler they exist) and define them afterwards (probably in a .cpp file for each class, though this is not the only possible layout).

In GameFlow.h:

```
class GameFlow{
public:
    int state;
    IController* controller;
    void changeState(); // this is a declaration
};
```

In GameFlow.cpp, include GameFlow.h and PlayerAttackController.h, then:

```
// this is a definition
void GameFlow::changeState()
{
    if(controller!=NULL){
        delete controller;
    }
    if(state==0){
        controller=new PlayerAttackController();
        controller->gameFlow=this;
    }else if(state==1){
        controller=new EnemyAttackController();
        controller->gameFlow=this;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Same for PlayerAttackController. In PlayerAttackController.h:

```
class PlayerAttackController : public IController{
public:
    GameFlow* gameFlow;
    void buttonPressed(); // this is a declaration
};
```

In PlayerAttackController.cpp, include both headers and:

```
// this is a definition
void PlayerAttackController::buttonPressed(){
    //some player attack code
    .
    .
    .
    gameFlow->state=1;
    gameFlow->changeState();
}
```

You'll want to define your functions in .cpp files anyway for other reasons - compile times are a big one.